# Unable to use apt-get because of python jasmine

Tags: apt, package-management

I had installed python jasmin for trying out. But now I am unable to remove it. Also it is causing problem while installing or updating other packages also. I get the following error while running `apt-get upgrade`

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
(Reading database ... 332480 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing python-jasmin (0.9.27) ...
Failed to stop jasmind.service: Unit jasmind.service not loaded.
dpkg: error processing package python-jasmin (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 5
Errors were encountered while processing:
 python-jasmin
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

adding the output of `apt-cache policy python-jasmin`

```
python-jasmin:
  Installed: 0.9.27
  Candidate: 0.9.27
  Version table:
 *** 0.9.27 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/jookies/python-jasmin/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 https://packagecloud.io/jookies/python-jasmin/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     0.9.26 500
        500 https://packagecloud.io/jookies/python-jasmin/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 https://packagecloud.io/jookies/python-jasmin/ubuntu xenial/main i386 Packages
```

also the file `/etc/init.d/jasmind` is empty.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The package’s maintainer scripts are broken, and you should remove them before attempting to uninstall the package:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/dpkg/info/python-jasmin.{pre,post}rm
sudo apt purge python-jasmin
```

This will restore your system to its previous state, mostly. You can clean up completely by following up with

```
sudo rm -rf /etc/jasmin /var/log/jasmin
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the service that is trying to stop it does not exist: did you installed successfully the package before you found this trouble?

Following the URL your sources.list(5) calls you can find:

*"last push: 8 months ago | 10 packages 
jookies is not collaborating on any repos..."*

It would be useful to know all steps you made [(if any)](https://www.queryxchange.com/q/2_1374673/unable-to-use-apt-get-because-of-python-jasmine/#) to avoid reiterating your effort finding the solution.

Comment: The error message indicates that the service exists, but isn’t running.